# How to use mutate in R programming?

Tags: r

The question goes like this. Use mutate to create a dollars_per_day variable, which is defined as gdp/population/365. Create the dollars_per_day variable for African countries for the year 2010. Remove any NA values. Save the mutated dataset as daydollars. My codes are below, is it possible to combine filter and mutate using mutate? Thanks!

```
#I used this code
library(dplyr) 
library(dslabs) 
data(gapminder) 
daydollars <- mutate(gapminder,continent=="Africa", year=2010, dollars_per_day=gdp/population/365,na.rm = TRUE) 
daydollars
```

Comment: Is this your homework? :-D

Comment: in the `gapminder` dataset there is no row with `year = 2010`. I see `max(gapminder$year)` as 2007

Comment: max(gapminder$year) is 2016

Comment: I'm confused — how does the user who posted this Q have the same username as me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```html
library(dplyr) 
library(dslabs) 
data(gapminder) 
daydollars <- mutate(
  gapminder,
  dollars_per_day= ifelse(is.na(gdp), 0, as.numeric(year==1960) * as.numeric(continent=="Africa") * gdp/population/365)
)
daydollars
```

The idea is to apply the filter by multiplying an expression with vectors of True/False.

Comment: please review now. I've tested it and edited the answer as necessary. You would need to decide what to do with the NA values in gdp. In this case I put them to zero